# PHP: How to create foreach loop (simple code)

Tags: php, loops, file-upload, foreach

I am new to PHP and have created a little code for a file upload on a form.

The code works fine but I was wondering if I could achieve the same using a foreach loop so that it could also handle more files and I dont have to write a separate line for each of them.

Can someone here help me with this and tell me how to write it properly.

**My Code (working):**

```
session_start();

$varUID = $_POST['UID'];
$varSender = $_SESSION['email'];

$varFile1 = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$varExt1 = pathinfo($varFile1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$varFile2 = $_FILES["file2"]["name"];
$varExt2 = pathinfo($varFile2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$varFile3 = $_FILES["file3"]["name"];
$varExt3 = pathinfo($varFile3, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $varUID . "_1" . "." . $varExt1);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $varUID . "_2" . "." . $varExt2);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file3"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $varUID . "_3" . "." . $varExt3);

echo $varUID;
```

Thanks for any help with this, 
Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
    $name = $file["name"];
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $key, $match); // get 2 out of "file2"
    $nr = $match[1];
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $varUID . "_" . $nr . "." . $ext);
}
```

Comment: This works perfect and I understand the way it's written - thanks a lot for the quick help !

Comment: I just saw you need to add something like $nr++ in the end as otherwise all files will get the same name.

Answer (score 3):

```
$varUID = $_POST['UID'];
$varSender = $_SESSION['email'];

$i = 1;

foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
    $varFile = $file[$key]["name"];
    $varExt = pathinfo($varFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($file[$key]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $varUID . "_" . $i . "." . $varExt);
    $i++;
}

echo $varUID;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the quick response. I tried but this doesnt work. Do I need to change anything here ? My names and IDs of my input fields are file1, file2 and file3.